# How to build an Qt application for Android using the AWS C++ SDK?

Tags: android, c++, qt, amazon-web-services

For several months I'm looking for **build an Qt application for Android using the AWS C++ SDK**. I searched on Internet but I found nothing...

I build the AWS C++ SDK for Android without problem like that :

```
*/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -DBUILD_ONLY="email;cognito-identity;lambda;core;cognito-idp;identity-management" -DNDK_DIR="/Users/bboglietti/Downloads/android-ndk-r10e" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++11" -DTARGET_ARCH=ANDROID -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/Users/bboglietti/aws_sdk/aws_build_android/build_android_dynamic" /Users/bboglietti/aws_sdk/aws-sdk-cpp-master*
```

But When I build my application, I have many errors of unreferenced links...

**Please, someone could put a brief Tutorial or Example?** It is working on MacOS, Windows, Linux, IOS but Android resists...

Answer (score 2):

Qt Applications needs a few additional environment setup for developing applications for android.

- Android SDK
- Android NDK
- Qt Version for android 
  You will need all these for making kits (ie. if you are using Qt Creator IDE, Otherwise you will have to use the CMake, qMake and C/C++ Compilers from android NDK).
  You can download Android studio, it will help you manage Android SDK and NDK

These links may help you start things up a bit

https://appbus.wordpress.com/category/qt-for-mobile/overview/

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer. I downloaded Android SDK and NDK.  I configured my QtCreator and it is working building a simple Android Application but when I add the AWS C++ SDK, I have unreferenced link issues.

Comment: @BenjaminB I don't think you can use AWS C++ SDK for building android application. I believe they are not supported to work on Android or iOS. I found [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=218847) in AWS Forum.

Comment: hi Kuncheria, thanks but I think it's not true. I did it for IOS and the official AWS documentation says that is working on ANDROID [here](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/sdk-for-cpp/) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/setup.html)

Comment: Have you set the environment variable then.

Comment: Yes, or I think yes. I configured my Qt (NDK 10 and last SDK) in the menu Reference>Device and I was able to build and deploy a simple app on a Android device. The issue occurs when I try to integrate the AWS C++ SDK library in my app.

Answer (score 0):

in mac ox, or console, set this:

- mkdir build_sdk_android
- cd build_sdk_android
- cmake path/aws-sdk-cpp/ -DNDK_DIR="path to /Android/sdk/android-ndk-r19c"     -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF     -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release     -DCUSTOM_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT=ON     -DTARGET_ARCH=ANDROID     -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=19     -DBUILD_ONLY="identity-management;s3;rekognition"     -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="path to install dir/build_sdk_android/install_sdk_desktop"
- make
- make install
- then place the .h headers, from the libraries you use from aws, for example:
  HEADERS + = \ work / aws-cpp-sdk-s3 / include / aws / s3 / model / AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload.h \
- However I have this error: pathAndroidinstall / include / aws / core / http / curl / CurlHandleContainer.h: 21: error: 'curl / curl.h' file not found #include